# JavaScript: Import module or add function to 'document'?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, frontend

I want to extend the vanilla DOM objects with new methods, for example extending `document.createElement()` by defining a new method `createElementWithAttrs()`, or extending `Element` but which of the following two is best practice?

**Approach A**

(like how [Chrome DevTools does it](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/devtools-frontend/src/front_end/dom_extension/DOMExtension.js), but it might because the code was inherited from WebKit long before the ES2015)

Add the new method to existing DOM class prototypes.

```js
// dom.js
Document.prototype.createElementWithClass = (tagName, className) => { ... };
Element.prototype.findEnclosingShadowRoot = () => { ... };
// probably a few more

// someScriptName.js
const e1 = document.createElementWithClass(...);
...
const shadow = e2.findEnclosingShadowRoot();
```

Pros:

- Concise and intuitive, because they can be used as if they are part of the native DOM

Cons:

- Have to insert `dom.js` in HTML with a `<script>` tag
- Sometimes confusing to readers (including myself, because after a long period of time I might forget).

**Approach B**:

Define them in an ES Module.

```js
// dom.js
export const createElementWithClass = (tagName, className) => { ... };
export const findEnclosingShadowRoot = (element) => { ... };
// probably a few more

// someScriptName.js
import * as dom from './dom.js';

const e1 = dom.createElementWithClass(...);
...
const shadow = dom.findEnclosingShadowRoot(e2);
```

Pros and Cons are the opposite of the "Cons" and "Pros" above.

Is there a best practice? Am I missing some pros/cons to consider? Thanks.

Comment: *and intuitive, because they can be used as if they are part of the native DOM* This is *not* intuitive at all IMO, because they don't exist on the native DOM. Defining a standalone function/class/module is probably a much better practice. Best to avoid mutating the built-in prototypes, it can often cause problems. Whether you define the functions (or mutate the prototypes) is orthogonal from whether you use a `<script>` tag or a `<script type="module">` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found an in-depth article analyzing why Approach A is **not recommended**: http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom, then main points being:

1. Lack of specification. The standard does not require `Document` and `Element` and others to be exposed.
2. Host objects have no rules (DOM objects are host objects): their behavior is implementation-dependent.
3. Name collisions.
4. Performance overhead.
5. Bugs in browsers, mainly in IE and some versions of Safari.